# passing every url through a routing file in php using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes

/
 .. .htaccess
 .. index.php

I have two files shown above in my servers root directory. I want to write a rule in .htaccess so that every time it will pass every parameters (i mean (.*)) to index.php?controller=parameter and index.php will route it accordingly. How can I write such a rule. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rewrites everything to index.php except for existing directories/files:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /pro/

RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   !-d
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   !-f
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$   index.php?controller=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Passing url to controller is not mandatory, since you can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` (for example) in your index.php

Comment: This works when I pass arguments, such as www.something.com/anything, but when using only www.something.com, it acts weird... why is that? In second case, can't it just open up my index.php in root dir??

Comment: When you reach root directory (`example.com` or `example.com/` or `example.com/index.php`) it will not rewrite so you have to check in your index: `if isset($_GET['controller'])`

Comment: Ok its like:
http://localhost/pro/adf , this works
but
http://localhost/pro/ will get me to

http://localhost/opt/lampp/htdocs/pro/localhost/pro/index.php?controller=

where am i missing things??

Comment: What is "pro" ? A virtual directory or an existing directory ? What is your document root ? Where is your htaccess ? In root level ?

Comment: its my project root directory inside "htdocs" of lampp, htdocs is my server's root dir and I have my project in "pro" directory

Comment: See my edited answer (your htaccess must be in your "pro" directory)

Comment: well, trick made some difference but, when i do: localhost/pro/adf, it will take me to  localhost/index, but i want it to remain in same directory..:(

Comment: With RewriteBase /pro/ ?

Comment: I made edits to take me to /pro/, and did the trick...thanks man..that saved me a lots of time..